# java.net.URL to refer to a CSS

Tags: java, css, url

How do I create a java.net.URL to refer to a CSS? Is it posible?

I've tried several other ways like this to check if its a css page but it doesn't work (no errors tho, but it doesn't):

```
        int code = con.getResponseCode();
        String type = con.getContentType();

        con.disconnect();

        //returns null if the connection had problems or its does not contain css
        if (code != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || !type.contains("stylesheet")) {
            return null;
        }
```

Any other posible solutions? Basically what I try to do is get the css page and print it.

Comment: A CSS page from a website is just another resource you can retrieve by making an HTTP request (that's what your browser does). Just send an HTTP GET to the url your CSS is located at.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis yeah but how do i get it if the given url and css location varies? Scanning for the link tag?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you scraping a page or do you know the exact url you want? Typically a css will be included with a `link` element that has a `ref="stylesheet"` attribute. `stylesheet` is not the content type, `text/css` is.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis is some sort of crawler for intranet websites so yeah "scraping"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the code below for example

```
URL url = new URL("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=e97b23688ee8"); // some css on this site
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getInputStream());
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) 
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());

System.out.println(con.getContentType()); // prints text/css
```

You were probably looking for the wrong `Content-Type`.

Comment: Genious! that's what i needed thanks, now I just need a way to somehow detect and get the css link from html code BUT THAT'S ANOTHER HISTORY :D

Comment: @eon You're welcome. There are libraries to scan HTML pages and extract information. For example, [`jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: I use jsoup but its the first time i use it and i just know how to get the HTML plane and simple or extract the title

Comment: @eon Step-by-step :) Also, consider accepting if the answer helped.

Comment: sure but i'm sure its not as simple as             Document do = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            String title = do.title();

Comment: need to wait my 6 min to accept it ;) You are lightning fast replying

Comment: @eon Maybe [this](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) will be helpful. I don't know jsoup, but you can definitely extract the elements that have a `ref="stylesheet"` attribute.

Comment: thanks alot sir, welcome to my little list of awesome people. Heh!